# Number of irreducible representations of finite group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

I'm reading Serre's Linear representations of finite groups, where on the begining of section 2.4, after proving the standard results about irreducible representations (Schur's lemma and its consequences), he starts with the sentence: “For the rest of Ch. 2, the irreducible characters of $G$ are denoted $X_1, ... , X_h$; their degrees are written $n_1, \dots , n_h$.”

I wonder, how can we talk about all the irreducible representations of $G$ (up to isomorphism)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We cannot talk about the set of all finite-dimensional linear irreducible representations of a group $G$; they do not form a set. But we can prove that, when $G$ is finite, then there is a set $\{X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_h\}$ of finite-dimensional linear representations of $G$, and then,when we work with that set, it's as if we were working with *all* finite-dimensional linear representations of $G$ (up to isomorphism).

Comment: Can you give a hint for the proof of that claim? Or maybe it's some famous thm with nice proof? I'm wondering since it doesn't apear in Serra's previous chapters and it comes like out of the blue

Comment: It's proved a little later (section 2.5, theorem 7).

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.